# How to set src attribute of [input=image] by external css

Tags: html, css, svg, imagebutton

I want to display an html with an input `type=image`.
I use a base64 svg string for the image.
When setting the `src` within the input attribute src - it works fine (btn1).

When setting the `src` via external css and setting image `class`, it doesn't work.

I Tried 2 different options btn2,bt3.

```html
<html>
    <style>
        .img2 {
            src: "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";
        }
        .img3 {
            src: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <input id="imgBtn1" type="image" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="Opss">
        <label for="imgBtn1">btn1 - att src</label>
        <br>
        <input id="imgBtn2" type="image" class="img2" alt="Opss">
        <label for="imgBtn2">btn2 - by css class</label>
        <br>
        <input id="imgBtn3" type="image" class="img3" alt="Opss">
        <label for="imgBtn3">btn3 - by css class</label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please advise.

Comment: You can't. CSS does not change the DOM it styles it.

Comment: @Paulie_D not sure I understand. The src att in not  css related att (just like height for instance is)?

Comment: Nope it's not. You need javascript

Comment: @Paulie_D how to do it with js?

Comment: updated my answer with js since it is okay for you to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CSS is not a **must**, then javascript is here to do the job.

example , setting your dataUri inside an array and and a loop on your inputs to update the `src` attribute:

```js
// set an array with each of your dataUris
const img =new Array ('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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' ,
' data:image/svg+xml;base64,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',

'data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');

// reset src attributes from dataUri stored in img()
let myIpts =document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="imgBtn"]');
for (i = 0; i < myIpts.length; i++) {
  myIpts[i].setAttribute('src', img[i] );
}
```

```html
<html>
<style>

</style>

<body>
  <input id="imgBtn1" type="image" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
    alt="Opss">
  <label for="imgBtn1">btn1 - att src</label>
  <br>
  <input id="imgBtn2" type="image" class="img2" alt="Opss">
  <label for=" imgBtn2 ">btn2 - by css class</label>
  <br>
  <input id="imgBtn3" type="image" class="img3" alt="Opss">
  <label for="imgBtn3 ">btn3 - by css class</label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more. Running the code snippet display also "empty image" for btn2,3. Is that why you said said example of the idea?

Comment: This won't work.  I don't think you can hide the "broken image" icon without also hiding the background image.   And saying "use a transparent svg image for src" defeats the purpose of what OP was trying to achieve.

Comment: @OJNSim, yes , the only way you can  show a different image from a CSS property here is to use background image, pseudo element also not an option (some carrousel do that , turning image into backgrounds ) .  To show that image, your button  image needs a size. You can either use a transparent image , so bg can be seen through it and be set via a class,. (similar to an old spacer.gif method from the past) . Or set a size, no `src` and  hide that `alt` text. **to me , the transparent image + bg could be okay for a design matter ,  sizing + bg +and hiding alt  text no => only a proof of concept.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau thks for your feedback. which browser did you use to run the snippet where it did not work ?  The transparent image (svg,png,gif) here would allow the bg to be seen. This button image here is used as an interactive icon and alt text stands here, but indeed won't be seen if style fails to load. Anyhow, there is no CSS way to modify a src attribute, this is a javascript task if not parsed ahead on the server side.

Comment: Ok, so you were expecting ppl to pretend there is a transparent PNG there? :)  By not providing that, you confused me, and apparently the OP also.  As it is now,, it appears to be a non-working solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `<img>` `src` attribute is not a property that you can style with CSS.

If you ***really*** need to style the button with CSS, you could do it this way:

It involves using a pseudo-element to cover up the contents of the `<input>` and setting its background to the SVG image.

It's a bit hacky, as it requires that you know in advance what the background colour behind the imput element is. And it'll almost certainly need to be a solid colour.

```css
#imgBtn2, #imgBtn3
{
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  color: transparent; /* hide alt text */
}

#imgBtn2::before, #imgBtn3::before
{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0IiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9ImN1cnJlbnRDb2xvciIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIiBzdHJva2UtbGluZWNhcD0icm91bmQiIHN0cm9rZS1saW5lam9pbj0icm91bmQiIGNsYXNzPSJmZWF0aGVyIGZlYXRoZXItcmVmcmVzaC1jY3ciPjxwb2x5bGluZSBwb2ludHM9IjEgNCAxIDEwIDcgMTAiPjwvcG9seWxpbmU+PHBvbHlsaW5lIHBvaW50cz0iMjMgMjAgMjMgMTQgMTcgMTQiPjwvcG9seWxpbmU+PHBhdGggZD0iTTIwLjQ5IDlBOSA5IDAgMCAwIDUuNjQgNS42NEwxIDEwbTIyIDRsLTQuNjQgNC4zNkE5IDkgMCAwIDEgMy41MSAxNSI+PC9wYXRoPjwvc3ZnPg==");
}
```

```html
<input id="imgBtn1" type="image" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" alt="Opss">
<label for="imgBtn1">btn1 - att src</label>
<br>
<input id="imgBtn2" type="image" class="img2" alt="Opss">
<label for="imgBtn2">btn2 - by css class</label>
<br>
<input id="imgBtn3" type="image" class="img3" alt="Opss">
<label for="imgBtn3">btn3 - by css class</label>
```

**Update**

If you don't need an `<input type="image/>` then I would suggest just using a `<button>` element. Then you can just style the background.

Here we separate out the button styling from the CSS class for the button icon.  So if you have buttons of the same type with different icons, you can reuse class `imgButton` and just give it a different icon class.

```css
.imgBtn
{
  border: none;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;

}

.reload
{
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="imgBtn reload"/>
```

Comment: hello, you are also hidding the text via color:transparent  :)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I don't **really** need css. What I didn't want is to have the image base64 string be part of the html, mainly for reading and editing purposes. Plus, in this case there's one such button, but in the general case there might be a situation where similar buttons exist in various places within the html. For this case I'd like to make the string reusable. So maybe css is not the way, and maybe I should ask what is the best way to achieve that. Also it doesn't have to be `input type=image`, but rather different element. My basic need is - image that will serve like a button.

Comment: @OJNSim , then js is your need :) , i'll update my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new solution for you.